# White space between medium-7 and medium-5 on the same line with Foundation

Tags: css

I need some help with some simple styling of two boxes I'm trying to make. I need to have some white space between them. I am using foundation, and have made one box which should fill medium-7 and another that will fill medium-5.

I just need some white space between them, but can't seem to do it.

**Code:**

```
<div class="main-container">
                <div class="row gutter">
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-7 color border-right">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column small-12">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-5 color border-left">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column small-12">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.color {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding-top: 0.8333rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.8333rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.border-left {
    border-left: 12px solid #ffffff;
}

.border-right {
    border-right: 12px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Have already tried with padding-left and padding-right, but nothing happens.
Also have tried with the border-left and right as you see, but then the box-shadow and border from the color class looks weird :(

What can I do here? any tricks?

**Image where only color class is applied:**

[image]

**Image where border-left and right and color class is applied:**

[image]

Comment: Both of the divs are going to take up 100% of their container, so you can't separate them with margin or it will cause the layout to break. You might want to give the second div a `medium-4`, or the first div a `medium-6`, then give either or margin to separate them.

Comment: So you mean, that if i set the one to the right with medium-4 and give it a margin-left it should work?

Comment: Yes, since both of the divs will add up to 91% of it's container. If you give the div on the right `medium-4`, and the div on left a certain amount of `margin-left` it should work. You will have to figure out the pixel amount of `margin-left`. You can do that just by trial and error.

Comment: That gives to much whitespace..

Comment: Then give the div on the left `padding-right` to increase its width. Or `padding-left` on the right div. Make sure you decrease the `margin` width when you do this to ensure the divs don't break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to get the required output::

```
.border-right {
border-right: 12px solid #ffffff;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.color {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
padding-top: 0.8333rem;
padding-bottom: 0.8333rem;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
border: 1px solid #CCC;
display: inline-block;
width: 48%;
}

.row.gutter{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your code helped me, but didn't used it all, specially the width: 48% did help me with some tweakings.

Thanks anyway for your quick help, good day.